# sessionStorage javascript, load getItem?

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

Good day everybody!

I have the following three functions for session storage, and i need some help with the loading-part. The savefunction works just fine, but i cant get the information back into the form, when loading the function loadform(). What am I doing wrong?

```
function book() {
    document.getElementById('ticketform').addEventListener('input', saveform, false);
    document.getElementById('ticketform').addEventListener('load', loadform, false);
}

function loadform() {
    var storedFnamn = sessionStorage.getItem('text1');
    var storedEnamn = sessionStorage.getItem('text2');
    var storedPnr = sessionStoage.getItem('text3');

    if (storedFnamn) {
        document.getElementById('firstname').value = storedFnamn;
    }
    if (storedEnamn) {
        document.getElementById('lastname').value = storedEnamn;
    }
    if (storedPnr) {
        document.getElementById('idnr').value = storedPnr;
    }
}

function saveform() {
    var fnamn = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var enamn = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var pnr = document.getElementById('idnr').value;

    window.sessionStorage.setItem('text1', fnamn);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('text2', enamn);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('text3', pnr);
}
```

Comment: Does `loadform` work by itself if you invoke manually? When are you expecting the _load_ event to fire?

Comment: I want the load event to fire when the page is loaded. I have tried to make it work by itself, but it didn't and I cant see what Im doing wrong. I have done this before, but with <body onload> and onclick, and now trying to do this with addEventListener and thought that that was the problem, but maybe there is something else.... :/

Comment: `loadform` looks okay. When is `book` invoked? It seems that the issue is probably to do with that/the load event - by the time you could `document.getElementById('ticketform')` the load event for `<form id="ticketform">` will have already been fired; put the load handler directly on window/document load

Comment: Thanks, that really helped!

Answer (score 0):

On line 9, in the `storedPnr` you misspelled `sessionStorage`, you wrote `sessionStoage`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't get a `load` event on the form element itself. I think what you want is to replace that line with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadform, false);
```

This way when the page's DOM has finished loading it will call the `loadform` method and pull in the values from session storage.